# Django : template variable form and select option value

Tags: django, forms, templates, variables, select

I have a template

```
<form action="" method="post">

<td >{{ form.droits_acces }}</td>
```

{{ form.droits_acces }} is a dropdown list with ('all', 'private', 'group')

if instead of write {{ form.droits_acces }}, I write

```
<select name="select">
 <option value="all">all</option> 
<option value="private">private</option>
<option value="group">group</option>
</select>
```

It is not the same and it does not work. Why ?

Comment: What do you mean by does not work? Yes, if you create your html elements manually, you'll not be able to validate them like `form.is_valid()` and in case of model forms you won't be able to save them directly.

Comment: I call the template with class Demande_Expertise(CreateView):..(views.py) and in my model I have class Demande_Expertise(models.Model) with def on_post_save(sender, instance, signal, created, **kwargs): I do not create the form. the problem is: I want to use jquery.It is easy to use it with 'select option value=..', and not with a variable {{  }} how to do in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why using jQuery means you don't want to use Django's form fields.

But your problem surely is that your `name` attribute is wrong: it should be `droits_acces`.

Comment: can i use something like : <select>
{% for p in form %}
<option value="{{p.form.droits_acces }}"</option>
{% endfor %}
  </select>

Comment: No. That doesn't make sense at all. `p` is each field in the form, none of the fields themselves have a `form` attribute, and anyway the options are attributes of the specific `droits_acces` field not the form itself.

Comment: this works <div id="selectMe">
{% for p in form.droits_acces %}
<td >{{ p }}</td>
{% endfor %}...................................................... I want to use  $('#selectMe').change(function () {
   
      if($(this).val()=="group"){
this test do not work because there is not select option in html